# Sum values from two lists using a function - no zip, map

Tags: python

I need solution to sum (addition) of each items of having same index.  I find the solution using map, zip, list comprehension. Is there any solution defining function.
My attempt:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

def add(a,b):
    for x in a:
        return(x)
        def add1(x,b):
            for b in b:
                return x + b

print (add(a,b))
```

Output from above is `1` which is wrong

Expected  output :`[5,7,9]`

Comment: Shoudn't your output be `[5, 7, 9]`?

Comment: Sorry I edited my post. Output should be` [5,7,9]`. But I am not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

def add(a, b):
    c = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c.append(a[i] + b[i])
    return c

print(add(a, b))
```

Output:

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Oh my god. You guys are great. I was taking it challenge and spent more than 12 hrs to improve my python coding.

Comment: @user1586957 I'm not sure that writing longer (and presumably slower) code without using optimized built-in functions will improve your coding by much.

Comment: @DeepSpace Maybe he is "purist" or he is coming from a C or Assembly background.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c=list()
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append(a[i]+b[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.add(a, b).tolist()
```

That is, you can define your function as:

```
def add(a, b):
    return np.add(a, b).tolist()
```

or,

```
add = lambda a, b: np.add(a, b).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code below to add if they have the same length

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c=[]
def add_array(a,b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c.append(a[i]+b[i])
    return c
print(add_array(a,b))
```

Or you could convert them to numpy arrays and add

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
def add_array(a,b):
    x=np.array(a)
    y=np.array(b)
    return x+y
print(add_array(a,b))
```

Comment: You should really define `c` in your function, as it is not initialized within the scope of your function, so if something else added elements to it in another part of the code, the `add_array` function would return an incorrect result

Comment: Your answer is really a bad version of @chrisz answer and my own answer. There is no need to convert `a` and `b` explicitly to arrays (see my answer).